Install dependencies of a git submodule in the root repository's node_modules folder?
I have a very specific build stack that I use across all of my client website projects which also includes gloablly-shared Vue components, and I'd like to make incremental universal changes to this build stack for all my clients as I continue to develop the stack. I have my stack repo setup as a git submodule in each of my client website repositories, but I'm struggling with refactoring all the dependencies to be stored and managed by the stack submodule.
Ideally, each client project would inherit all the dependencies of the stack repo automatically, so as I update the version of stack as I continue to develop it, client website repositories receive and install the updated dependencies of stack when they update the version of stack they are using.
For example...

website-one.com repository has only one dependency: stack (as a submodule)
website-two.com repository has only one dependency: stack (as a submodule)
etc...

stack repo contains all the top-level dependencies for each website project (vue, vite, laravel, inertiajs, ...)
How do I configure the submodule relationship within each website project's repo so that all the stack dependencies are installed at the top level in <root>/node_modules instead of <root>/stack/node_modules?
My directory structure for each project is like...
stack
| - package.json
node_modules
| - ...
package.json

and I'd like for my root package.json file to have a (simple) dependency list as follows:
"dependencies": {
    "stack": "file:stack"
}

so that when I add a dependency to the stack/package.json file, it is installed in <root>/node_modules (at the root level of the project).
FYI, I'm using PNPM, and I've tried Bit with no success.

You've already put node_modules in your .gitignore, right?

I'm not sure how that relates to the issue. Does node_module being in the .gitignore file prevent it's packages from being discovered in the root project?

node_modules is going to be huge, and all of its contents should be described elsewhere (usually in package.json, which should be under version control). You should not keep its actual contents in any Git repo.

Yeah that has nothing to do with the subject of this post. FWIW, I do have node_modules in my .gitignore file and I don't commit it's contents to my repo.

Solved this issue by setting: hoist-workspace-packages=true in my .npmrc file
